# proof - infinite pair integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a + b = 100$ and $\gcd(a, b) = 5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Prove that there are an infinite pair integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a + b = 100$ and $\gcd(a, b) = 5$.

I don't know how to proceed with this. Especially, proving that they are infinite. There was another problem when the GCD was 3 and I had to prove there existed no such combination, which I did with ease.

I have tried but have made no progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a+b)$, so it's enough to make sure $\gcd(a,100)=5$ and choose $b$ so that $a+b=100$.

Comment: @Wojowu But how do we get an infinite number of $a$'s.

Comment: You can show that $a=100k+5$ for any integer $k$ will work. This is all hints I'm going to give you.

Comment: @Wowoju Please check my proof. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Wojowu, I am able to present my proof. If you find any error or flaws please comment.

**Proof:**

$\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \gcd(100k+5, -(100k - 95)) = 5$

As, $\gcd(100k + 5, 100k - 95) = \gcd(100k + 5, 100k - 95 - (100k + 5)) = \gcd(5(20k+1), 5(20))$ which is equal to $5$ as $20k +1$ is relatively prime to $20$. Thus there are infinitely many pairs of integers that satisfy the given criteria.

Comment: Looks fine. The only mistake I see is you misspelling my nick :)